# Dynamic type deduction equivalent of std::is_convertible

Tags: c++, dynamic, type-conversion, type-deduction

I want to call the proper template function based on what is the dynamic type of the held value of a pointer. I tried using `std::is_convertible`, but it only checks for implicit convertibility. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

struct A           { A() = default; virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B: public A { B() = default; virtual ~B() = default; };
struct C: public A { C() = default; virtual ~C() = default; };

template <typename T> 
std::string get_type_string(std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, A>::value, T*>)
{
    return "A";
}

template <typename T> 
std::string get_type_string(std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, B>::value, T*>)
{
    return "B";
}

template <typename T> 
std::string get_type_string(T*)
{
    return "unknown";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> container;
    container.emplace_back(new B());
    container.emplace_back(new B());
    container.emplace_back(new C());

    for(const auto& value: container)
    {
        auto ptr = value.get();
        std::cout << "Element of type: " << get_type_string(ptr) << ", ";
        std::cout << "Real type: " << (dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr) ? "B" : dynamic_cast<C*>(ptr) ? "C" : "unknown") << '\n';
    }
}
```

This code results:

> Element of type: unknown, Real type: B
>
> Element of type: unknown, Real type: B
>
> Element of type: unknown, Real type: C

Is there a way to write an overloaded function that tries to dynamically deduce the type of the passed parameter or is listing the `dynamic_cast` attempts explicitly the only way to go?

**Since many comments ask why I don't modify the data structures themselves:**
`class B, C, etc.` is the data objects I want to handle based on their type. I am provided with a generic data file (generated by people using the same data framework) and I read this in from the hard disk. When I ask the data framework what keys are available in a given data file it gives me a list consisting of a generic base pointer type (in the example it is denoted with `class A`). I want to operate on the elements of this list, but what I want to do depends on the underlying type.

Comment: Calling different functions depending on the object's dynamic type sounds a lot like the purpose of virtual functions. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I have a specific data object that is read in from files. Then I loop on this data, but when I loop on the keys I am only given keys that are pointers of a generic Object type. I want to write a function that performs different operations based on the actual type of the data, for example if it is a histogram, copy it to a collection, if it is another directory, call the same function on it recursively, etc...

Comment: Why don't you write a virtual function for your generic object type?

Comment: sounds like the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: @xskxzr Because I am not able to modify the data structure itself. It is a generic data format handled by a data framework.

Comment: @Caleth I added some more information to clarify the problem I am facing.

Comment: I think you cannot use polymorphism properly here because polymorphism works together with virtual functions in C++. I am not familiar with the visitor pattern, but as I know, it needs an `accept` method, which means you still need to modify your library class. Maybe storing pointer with some additional information (to identify its dynamic type) together is an imperfect solution.